# How to integrate FileMaker (ODBC) in Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I use filemaker as crm and I am looking for how to integrate tables in Google Data Studio.

I know that there is not a connector created in Data Studio, I ask around here in case someone has the same case.

In Power BI if I have it integrated, but most of the dashboards are in Data Studio.

Thank you

Comment: Hello. Please post your code as there is no code to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no FileMaker connector availabe for Data Studio. If you're interested in making one, please see our [Get Started](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/get-started) guide.